# Directive never gets called angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

We are creating a directive to Increase and Descrease a number in a text box when user clicks on the buttons.

Here is the code of my custom directive.

```
var CEDirectives = angular.module('App.customnumberdirectives', [])
.directive('ngcustomNumber', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
var TEMPLATE_URL = '/customnumber/index.html';
var tem = '<div class="wrapper">' +
          '  <input type="text" data-ng-model="{{model}}" data-ng-blur="onBlurHandler()">' +
          '  <button ng-click="Increase()" style="cursor:pointer; background-color: transparent">INC</button>' +
          '  <button ng-click="Decrease()" style="cursor:pointer; background-color: transparent">DEC</button>' +
          '</div>';

// Set the default template for this directive
$templateCache.put(TEMPLATE_URL,tem);

return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
        model: '@',
        onblurevent: '&'
    },
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: function (element, attrs) {
        return attrs.templateUrl || TEMPLATE_URL;
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attributes) {

        scope.onBlurHandler = function () {
            if (scope.onblurevent) {
                scope.onblurevent();
            }
        };

        scope.Increase = function () {
            alert('Inc');
        };
        scope.Decrease = function () {
            alert('Dec');
        };
    }
};
} ]);
```

In the html view:-

```
 <ngcustomNumber model="weight" onblurevent="Save"></ngcustomNumber>
```

(1) No error in Console.

(2) Tried putting alert on the top of the directive. No alert message comes up.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hav you applied ngApp in your html

Comment: Yes. Its in the HTML tag.

Comment: App.customnumberdirectives  is your module name just to confirm ?

Comment: Have you added the reference\dependency of `'App.customnumberdirectives'` to your main app module.

Comment: Is your directive loaded in the browser?

Comment: @Riturajratan Yes correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ngcustom-number model="weight" onblurevent="Save"></ngcustom-number>
```

Comment: Worked. But may I know is it mandatory to write directive in the similar way?

Comment: You have set `restrict:'E'`, which means only element is allowed. use `AE` otherwise if you want to use as attribute

Comment: since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model). https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization

Answer (score 0):

Because your compile is not done with right way.You must be sure that given scope IS ON template.For checking it you can print scope id in template.As you know every scope has it's ID,so if directive scope and template scope id is not the same,your problem is in it,and the solution is:

to compile it with right way.passing in it your directive's scope.
the $compile service: $compile(template)(directiveScope);

you can console the scope and will see the fields I'm talking about